# Java making switch case statment shorter

Tags: java, switch-statement, case, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have this `switch case statement` in my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. And I have looked into many similar questions but none have provided a shorter answer, meaning the `switch` cases are still in their code.

This code is really repetitive and ugly to look at. Is there a way to make this look shorter?

```
@Override
public SongListFragment getItem(int position) {
    SongListFragment slf = new SongListFragment();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            slf.setAudioList(getAudioList(tabTitles[0]));
            slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                    itemListener.onClick(audio);
                }
            });
            return slf;
        case 1:
            slf.setAudioList(getAudioList(tabTitles[1]));
            slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                    itemListener.onClick(audio);
                }
            });
            return slf;
        case 2:
            slf.setAudioList(getAudioList(tabTitles[2]));
            slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                    itemListener.onClick(audio);
                }
            });
            return slf;
        case 3:
            slf.setAudioList(getAudioList(tabTitles[3]));
            slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                    itemListener.onClick(audio);
                }
            });
            return slf;
        case 4:
            slf.setAudioList(getAudioList(tabTitles[4]));
            slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                    itemListener.onClick(audio);
                }
            });
            return slf;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the code in each case. Mark the common parts, and the difference: every thing is the same except one integer, and that's the switch value...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As every switch case has almost the same body, just the index/position is different. You can completly get rid of the switch case in the first place:

```
@Override
public SongListFragment getItem(int position) {
     SongListFragment slf = new SongListFragment();
     slf.setAudioList(getAudioList(tabTitles[position]));
     slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(Audio audio) {
            itemListener.onClick(audio);
        }
     });
     return slf;
}
```

Comment: you would need bound checks on `tabTitles` else you would get AIOOB exception.

Comment: Eh.. Now I feel like a fool.. I used case switches because I thought it was neccesary to swap between tablyout tabs, but as it seems, it does not require it. Anyways, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Lino 's answer with a simple bound check as @SMA suggested.

```
@Override
public SongListFragment getItem(int position) {
     if ( position < 0 || position >= tabTiles.length() ){
       //your previous default case
       return null;
     }else{
       SongListFragment slf = new SongListFragment();
       slf.setAudioList(getAudioList(tabTitles[position]));
       slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(Audio audio) {
              itemListener.onClick(audio);
            }
          });
     return slf;
   }
}
```

Comment: The source we're getting the position from is probably backed by the same data source as `tabTitles` (or whatever produces `tabTitles`). If so, it won't be possible for the position to ever be out of bounds. Returning `null`, however, is just begging for a `NullPointerException` in whatever code calls this.

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
  @Override
public SongListFragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return yourMethod(0);
        case 1:
            return yourMethod(1);
        case 2:
            return yourMethod(2);
        case 3:
            return yourMethod(3);
        case 4:
            return yourMethod(4);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

private Object yourMethod(int i) {
    SongListFragment slf = new SongListFragment();
    slf.setAudioList(getAudioList(tabTitles[i]));
    slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(Audio audio) {
            itemListener.onClick(audio);
        }
    });
    return slf;
}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that this code is unnecessarily complicated and worse than the accepted answer, it doesn't even compile.

Comment: I didn't see the accepted answer before I publish it, cause I already was with the question opened.

Comment: `Public` is not Java. There is no reason not to declare the return type more narrowly. There is no reason, and never was, for this code to use a `switch` statement at all.

Comment: Now I noticed it.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public SongListFragment getItem(int position) {
    // don't need to initialize
    SongListFragment slf = null;
    // The position is 0 to 4, returns null when position is over tabTiles.length() 
    if (position >= 0 && position <= 4 
        && position < tabTiles.length()) {
        slf = new SongListFragment();
        slf.setAudioList(getAudioList(tabTitles[position]));
        slf.setItemOnClickListener(new SongListFragment.SongListItemOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Audio audio) {
                itemListener.onClick(audio);
            }
        });
    }
    // returns SongListFragment if it is null or not
    return slf;
}
```